# How to find nodes being contained in a node's properties interval?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently developing some kind of a configurator using neo4j as a backend. Now I ran into a problem, I don't know how to solve best.

I've got nodes created like this:

`(A:Product {name:'ProductA', minWidth:20, maxWidth:200, minHeight:10, maxHeight:400})
(B:Product {name:'ProductB', minWidth:40, maxWidth:100, minHeight:20, maxHeight:300})`

...

There is an interface where the user can input a desired width & height, f.e. Width=30, Height=250. Now I'd like to check which products match the input criteria. As the input might be any long value, the approach used in http://neo4j.com/blog/modeling-a-multilevel-index-in-neoj4/ with dates doesn't seem to be suitable for me. How can I run a cypher query giving me all the nodes matching the input criteria?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand well what you are asking for, but if I do, here a simple query to get this:

#### Assuming the user wants width = 30 and height = 50

```
Match (p:Product)
WHERE 
    p.minWidth < 30 AND p.maxWidth > 30 AND
    p.minHeight < 50 AND p.maxHeight > 50
RETURN
    p
```

If this is not what you are looking for, feel free to say it as comment.